# qt c++ qpainter with QVector

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

So I have an `QVector` called xarray

```
QVector< QString > xarray;
```

Now I want to draw the array

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* e )
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "\r\narr : " <<QList<QString>::fromVector(xarray);
        painter.drawEllipse(X, 10, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

How can I give the array to my x comp ?

I tried

```
painter.drawEllipse(xarray[i], 10, 100, 100);
```

But there is no function for call to `QPainter`.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, strings aren't numbers. Why is your vector not of ints (or floats or something).

Comment: my array is pushed by an XML file. If i choose float or double he cannot read my file anymore :-(

Comment: What is `X` in the code? how is `i` being used inside `for` loop? Too many assumptions are required to understand what is the actual purpose of the code. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @user3676560: bring out `QString` from your array in loop. Then convert it to `int`

Comment: the X is the spot where ill put my array. With "i" ill  loop the array

Comment: @user3676560 What do you mean by "i'll put my array". This question is very poorly worded and explained. You really have to put some effort into making your questions clear and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [QString::toInt()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt).

You have an array of QStrings but you need to pass an int to [drawEllipse()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawEllipse-3), the overload that takes ints. You will need to convert your strings to integers.

A quick edit to your code would turn it into:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       qDebug() << "\r\narr : " <<QList<QString>::fromVector(xarray);
       painter.drawEllipse(xarray[i].toInt(), 10, 100, 100);
    }
 }
```

I didn't actually compile that, hope it works and you get the idea.

Comment: i get an error msg: no matching function for call to 'QPainter::drawEllipse(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, int, int)'
     painter.drawEllipse(xarray[i].toInt, 10, 100, 100);

Comment: Can you copy-paste the exact line with drawEllipse from your file?

Comment: painter.drawEllipse(xarray[i].toInt, 10, 100, 100);

Comment: Yep. I had a feeling about that from the error message :).

Answer (score 2):

A naive implementation could look like:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        painter.drawEllipse(xarray[i].toFloat(), 10.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    }
}
```

You need to convert `QString` value into `float` value before use it as an argument for `drawEllipse`

But in real code I strongly recommend to make sure that values in `xarray` can be converted to `float` before use them.